# PostgreSQL assigning random, non-repeating values

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, window-functions

I have a table of students that looks like this:

```
   firstname    | id 
----------------+----
 Student1       |  1
 Student2       |  2
 Student3       |  3
 Student4       |  4
 Student5       |  5
 Student6       |  6
 Student7       |  7
 Student8       |  8
 Student9       |  9
```

and a table containing the number of tasks to be performed per topic like this:

```
 topic   | n_tasks
---------+----
       1 | 11
       2 |  3
       3 |  6
       4 |  9
       5 | 12
       6 | 13
       7 | 10
       8 | 25
       9 | 10
      10 | 10
      11 | 22
      12 | 20
      14 | 18
      15 | 18
      16 |  7
```

I would like to assign tasks to students at random, subject to the following rules:

- When there are exactly the same number of tasks as students, each
  student should be randomly assigned to a task number.
- When there are more tasks than students, the list of students should
  repeat.
- When there are fewer tasks than students, the list of tasks should
  repeat.
- Where repetition in either students or tasks is necessary, these should be selected at random.

The output could be stored in separate tables, one for each task. It would look like this:

```
table topic1

   firstname    | task 
----------------+----
 Student1       |  1
 Student8       |  2
 Student4       |  3
 Student3       |  4
 Student7       |  5
 Student9       |  6
 Student6       |  7
 Student7       |  8
 Student8       |  9
 Student1       |  10
 Student2       |  11

table topic2

   firstname    | task 
----------------+----
 Student1       |  1
 Student2       |  2
 Student3       |  3
 Student4       |  1
 Student5       |  3
 Student6       |  2
 Student7       |  2
 Student8       |  3
 Student9       |  1
```

Where repetition of either tasks or students would be necessary, ideally neither the student nor the task would repeat until all other students or tasks have been exhausted.

After reflection, I am thinking this problem may be ill-suited for PostgreSQL and might be better done in another programming language, but thanks for any advice!

Comment: Nope above scenario is not ill-Suited for PostgreSQL. Try the below solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Function for your requirement:

```
create or replace function fun(topic_id int) returns bool as
$$
declare
st_count int;
topic_count int;
begin
select count(*) into st_count from student;
select n_tasks into topic_count from topic where topicid=topic_id;

if st_count=topic_count and st_count>0 and topic_count>0 then
execute format('create table %I (first_name varchar, task int)','topic'||topic_id);
execute format('insert into %I select name,row_number() over (order by random()) rn from student','topic'||topic_id);
return true;
end if;


if st_count>topic_count and st_count>0 and topic_count>0 then
execute format('create table %I (first_name varchar, task int)','topic'||topic_id);
execute format('insert into %I 
with cte as (select generate_series(1,%s) rn), 
cte1 as (
select row_number() over (order by random()) rn, 
name from student t1) select t1.name, coalesce(t2.rn,round(random()* %s)) 
from cte1 t1 left join cte t2 on t1.rn=t2.rn',
'topic'||topic_id,topic_count,topic_count);

return true;
end if;

if st_count<topic_count and st_count>0 and topic_count>0 then
execute format('create table %I (first_name varchar, task int)','topic'||topic_id);
execute format('insert into %I with cte as (select generate_series(1,%s) rn),
cte1 as (select row_number() over (order by random()) rn, name from student t1),
cte2 as (select coalesce(t2.rn, round(random()* %s)) rn_,t1.rn from cte t1 
left join cte1 t2 on t1.rn=t2.rn) 
select t1.name,t2.rn from cte2 t2 inner join cte1 t1 on t1.rn=t2.rn_',
'topic'||topic_id,topic_count,st_count);

return true;
end if;


return false;
end;

$$
language plpgsql
```

Then you can call above function like below:

```
select fun(topicid) from topic;
```

this will generate all tables with given condition.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a6484abdfdd96163352760ec0491e05b)

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting question.

First, you can start by creating task rows with `generate_series()`. Then, you can randomly enumerate the students.

Finally, you can use arithmetics in the join condition to take in account "missing" rows on each end: the idea is to compare the number of tasks to the number of students, and then use modulo to offset the values of the biggest group, and properly distribute otherwise unmatched rows.

```
select s.firstname, t.task
from (
    select 
        s.*, 
        row_number() over(order by random()) rn,
        count(*) over() cnt
    from students s
) s
inner join (
    select t.*, x.task
    from topic t
    cross join lateral generate_series(1, n_tasks) as x(task)
) t 
    on (s.cnt     <= t.n_tasks  and s.rn   = t.task % s.cnt     + 1)
    or (t.n_tasks <  s.cnt      and t.task = s.rn   % t.n_tasks + 1)
where t.topic = 1
order by t.topic, t.task
```

You can add a `where` clause to the query to filter on a given topic.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a1a42be87858763461bddd24afdd4d3a)**:

For topic 1:

```
firstname | task
:-------- | ---:
Student6  |    1
Student3  |    2
Student7  |    3
Student5  |    4
Student8  |    5
Student2  |    6
Student4  |    7
Student1  |    8
Student9  |    9
Student6  |   10
Student3  |   11
```

For topic 2:

```
firstname | task
:-------- | ---:
Student9  |    1
Student3  |    1
Student7  |    1
Student1  |    2
Student6  |    2
Student8  |    2
Student4  |    3
Student2  |    3
Student5  |    3
```